# "Hate best" or "hate worst"?

Tags: word-usage

As I was listening to Homer's hate song to Ned Flanders on *The Simpsons*, a particular line made me wonder; can someone hate something (the) best? I've certainly heard "hate (the) most". Could something just as equally be hated (the) worst?

> F-L-A-N-R-D-S!
>   **He's the man that I hate best!**
>   I'd like to see his house go up in flames!

Source: [Flanders is His Name](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Flanders_is_His_Name)

Comment: I'd call it "poetic license". :-)

Comment: @ralph.m Surreal. Epic.

Comment: It's meant to be comical. Generally it would be "He's the man I *like* best," this is just inverting it while using the same sentence structure.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Explaining a joke makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @Ricky Note the *upvote* on the comment. Solid proof it was helpful right there.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Sure. Let me give you another one since you like them so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, normally, you wouldn't say "hate best". You'd say "hate (the) most".

But as Ralph mentioned in the comments, this is a clear example of **poetic license**:

> the freedom that poets and other artists have to change facts, **ignore grammar rules** etc, because what they are making is poetry or art

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poetic-licence))

EDIT: Regarding "hate most" vs "hate worst": I don't have an authoritative reference, but both appear to be acceptable according to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hate_VERB+most%2Chate_VERB+worst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chate_VERB%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chate_VERB%20worst%3B%2Cc0) (albeit "hate most" is *far* more frequently used).

Interestingly enough, there is [no huge difference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like_VERB%20most%2Clike_VERB%20best&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike_VERB%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike_VERB%20best%3B%2Cc0) frequency-wise between the interchangeable "like best" and "like most".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you able to update your answer to provide an explanation of whether "hate (the) worst" is acceptable?

Comment: @DogLover No problem, see my updated answer.